# How to create user control [common control] in iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to create a common view / control which will be used in many view controller pages. For e.g. header control which has logo, logout and home button which will be used in many other view controller pages in Xmarin iOS.

Is there any way to create 1 common control / view which I can use any all the pages so if any updates in future, I can change it from 1 page only without updating in all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Custom Controls for iOS? If yes, Xamarin has a couple of articles for that in their guides: [explanation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_overview/) and [walkthrough](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/ios_designable_controls_walkthrough/). The designer even supports the custom controls which are a subclass of `UIView` or `UIViewController`. I guess all information you need should be there.

Comment: Could you please provide some code examples? I am new to Xamarin iOS development and have already gone through the links you provided but didn't help much.